# Sockopt or other option to ignore 'connection refused' in a UDP connection?

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, posix

I have a UDP socket where I set the source address on with `bind` and remote address with `connect`. When I use the `send` function the only feedback I get is bytes sent count and an explanation for an under-send with `perror`.

When the remote address is not listening, even though I sent the packet, the ICMP message sent back triggers the bytes sent value to be `0` and `perror` returns `Connection refused`.

Is there any way to tell the OS to ignore this case, and treat it like a successful and return the number of bytes sent on the wire?

Comment: `0` isn't an error-return from `send()`; errno only gets set when `send()` returns -1.  The `Connection refused` error you are seeing is coming from some other/previous operation.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I scoped the final question more. Per the perror, there is no other operation that is not being checked, so I am just going to table that for the time being.

Comment: what does perror() print out *immediately before* you call `send()` ?

Comment: What ICMP message? How does that come into play?

Comment: @Shawn the ICMP message is Type 3, Code 3: "Destination unreachable (port unreachable)". It is being sent from the remote OS saying, that currently has nothing listening on that port.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner perror return `Success` before and after on the first send, then on the second loop it prints `Success` before and then ` Connection refused` after. So I am really thinking that the ICMP is triggering the bytes sent to go to 0 and setting the perror.

Comment: Interesting. I've never gotten an error back when nothing's receiving udp packets... Some research indicates it only happens with connected sockets, which explains why I've never seen it in my projects (I've never used connect() with udp)

Comment: @Shawn yeah the connect lets we use normal `send` `recv` so I can swap TCP and UDP sockets pretty easily. Also makes it easier to multiplex on a single udp port.